# I am getting a error message for getwaiter

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting the error message "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

> Error  CS4036  'IAsyncOperation' does not contain
> a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type
> 'IAsyncOperation' could be found (are you
> enter code here missing a using directive for 'System'?).

```
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BasicGeoposition startLocation = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 47.643, Longitude = -122.131 };

        // End at the city of Seattle, Washington.
        BasicGeoposition endLocation = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 47.604, Longitude = -122.329 };

        // Get the route between the points.
        MapRouteFinderResult routeResult =
            await MapRouteFinder.GetDrivingRouteAsync(new Geopoint(startLocation), new Geopoint(endLocation), MapRouteOptimization.Time, MapRouteRestrictions.None);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following at the beginning of your .cs file

```
using System;
```

If that doesn't work, add the 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop/ package to your project

Comment: I have that included